# List databases using python sqlite3 API

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Is there a way to list all attached databases for a sqlite3 `Connection`?  For instance:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("attach database 'a.db' as 'a'")
con.execute("attach database 'b.db' as 'b'")
con.list_databases() # <- doesn't exist
```

The command with the `sqlite3` command shell is `.databases`.  Tried poking at `sqlite_master` but of course that's a table, and it exists on each attached DB.  I see nothing in the docs either.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it by digging into the sqlite3 source code:

`c.execute("PRAGMA database_list").fetchall()`

Forgot about PRAGMAs

(https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L8417)

Comment: Why the source code and not documentation?

Comment: @PChemGuy I looked at the documentation first (I love the sqlite3 docs), but without the magic word "pragma" I didn't find anything.  I knew that the sqlite3 cmdline utility is basically just a thin wrapper around the C library so it wasn't hard to find there.